# Function Consuming High CPU in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have came across one function on our client environment which is consuming CPU.

Below is the query.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fnEncClaimType](@in_ApptOrEncId numeric(8),@in_bool_IsApptId numeric(2)) 
returns varchar(20)
as
begin 
    declare @returnVal varchar(20)
    set @returnVal = ''
    if @in_bool_IsApptId = 1 begin 
        SELECT TOP 1 @returnVal = CASE 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'AUTO' THEN 'Auto Accident' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'EMPLOYER' THEN 'Employer' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PATCLM' THEN 'Self Pay' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PATINV' THEN 'Penalty Invoice' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PI' THEN 'Penalty Invoice' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'INJURY' THEN 'Personal Accident' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PROF' THEN 'Professional' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'TPA' THEN 'TPA' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'UB04' THEN 'Institutional' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'WORKCOMP' THEN 'Work Comp' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'DMERC' THEN 'DMERC' ELSE '' 
        END FROM TRN_BILLING_HEAD,TRN_ENCOUNTERS 
        WHERE BLH_ENC_ID = ENC_ID 
        AND (BLH_APPT_ID = @in_ApptOrEncId OR ENC_APPT_ID = @in_ApptOrEncId) 
        AND BLH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0 
        ORDER BY BLH_ID end 
    else begin 
        SELECT TOP 1 @returnVal = CASE 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'AUTO' THEN 'Auto Accident'
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'EMPLOYER' THEN 'Employer' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PATCLM' THEN 'Self Pay' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PATINV' THEN 'Penalty Invoice'
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PI' THEN 'Penalty Invoice' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'INJURY' THEN 'Personal Accident' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PROF' THEN 'Professional' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'TPA' THEN 'TPA' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'UB04' THEN 'Institutional' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'WORKCOMP' THEN 'Work Comp' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'DMERC' THEN 'DMERC' ELSE '' END 
        FROM TRN_BILLING_HEAD 
        WHERE BLH_ENC_ID = @in_ApptOrEncId AND BLH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0 
        ORDER BY BLH_ID
    end

    return @returnVal 
end;
```

I had checked the execution plan to check for indexes and it is using appropriate indexes performing index seek.

Can anyone please suggest any query level changes required to optimise this.
I am not a developer hence finding it difficult to check for any query level optimisation.

Comment: If it is using appropriate indices like you are saying, it should be instant as it would be returning one row using these indices. If you are calling it for every row in an outer query however, it is supposed to be slow because it's multistep. Rewrite it to be inline.

Comment: Some *good* formatting (use of line breaks and white space) really would *not* go amiss in that object's definition.

Comment: When I *did* make this look well formatting, a couple of comments: 1. It's 2021, why are you *still* using that 1980's implicit JOIN syntax? It was superseded with the explicit join syntax in *1992*. 2. This is going to be have to be parsed as a multi-line scalar function, which can be *very* slow. 3. What is it trying to achieve? If you convert it to an **inline** (that's ***inline***) table value function, you might (will?) get much better performance.

Comment: One essential question here is, how are you using this? If you're calling it with a single value it's a completely different thing than if you're applying this to a query with 10 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalar functions are slow, inline functions are fast. Let's start with that. You can rewrite your scalar udf as an inline table valued function that returns one row/one column:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fnEncClaimType_itvf](@in_ApptOrEncId numeric(8),@in_bool_IsApptId numeric(2)) 
returns table as return
(
    SELECT TOP 1 returnVal = CASE 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'AUTO' THEN 'Auto Accident' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'EMPLOYER' THEN 'Employer' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PATCLM' THEN 'Self Pay' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PATINV' THEN 'Penalty Invoice' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PI' THEN 'Penalty Invoice' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'INJURY' THEN 'Personal Accident' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PROF' THEN 'Professional' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'TPA' THEN 'TPA' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'UB04' THEN 'Institutional' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'WORKCOMP' THEN 'Work Comp' 
        WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'DMERC' THEN 'DMERC' ELSE '' 
        END 
    FROM TRN_BILLING_HEAD,TRN_ENCOUNTERS 
    WHERE @in_bool_IsApptId = 1
      AND BLH_ENC_ID = ENC_ID 
      AND (BLH_APPT_ID = @in_ApptOrEncId OR ENC_APPT_ID = @in_ApptOrEncId) 
      AND BLH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0 
    ORDER BY BLH_ID
)
UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 1 returnVal = CASE 
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'AUTO' THEN 'Auto Accident'
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'EMPLOYER' THEN 'Employer' 
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PATCLM' THEN 'Self Pay' 
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PATINV' THEN 'Penalty Invoice'
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PI' THEN 'Penalty Invoice' 
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'INJURY' THEN 'Personal Accident' 
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'PROF' THEN 'Professional' 
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'TPA' THEN 'TPA' 
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'UB04' THEN 'Institutional' 
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'WORKCOMP' THEN 'Work Comp' 
      WHEN BLH_PATINV_TEXT = 'DMERC' THEN 'DMERC' ELSE '' END 
    FROM TRN_BILLING_HEAD 
    WHERE BLH_ENC_ID = @in_ApptOrEncId AND BLH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0 
    ORDER BY BLH_ID
GO
```

This:

```
SELECT dbo.fnEncClaimType(1,2);
```

Becomes:

```
SELECT returnValue FROM dbo.fnEncClaimType_itvf(1,2);
```

This:

```
SELECT dbo.fnEncClaimType(1,2)
FROM   <some table>
```

Becomes:

```
SELECT      cl.returnValue 
FROM        <some table>
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnEncClaimType_itvf(1,2) AS cl;
```

Comment: Another syntax is `SELECT (SELECT returnValue FROM dbo.fnEncClaimType_itvf(1,2)) FROM        <some table>`